# setNextMediaPlayer with the same variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

i'm new in android programming. what i want to do is to play sounds without overlapping the other sound. what i tried is the setNextMediaPlayer as suggested to me and it worked but what if i have set of random array like for example a4,a4,c4,b4,a4,b4 depending on the user input.

for example the user input is: a4,a4,c4,b4,a4,b4

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tempq.size(); i++) {
            String u =tempq.get(i);

            //WHOLE
            if (u.equals("a4")){
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a4);
                mp.start();


            }else if (u.equals("b4")){
                MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b4);
                mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp1);


            }else if (u.equals("c4")){
                MediaPlayer mp2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c4);
                mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);


            }
        }
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

UPDATED CODE:

code for adding list in refList:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < tempq.size(); i++) {
            final String u =tempq.get(i);

            if (u.equals("a4")){
                refList.add(R.raw.a4);
                Log.d("References", refList.toString());
            }else if (u.equals("b4")){
                refList.add(R.raw.b4);
                Log.d("References", refList.toString());
            }
        }
```

code for playing sounds

```
   for (int i = 0; i < refList.size(); i++) {

        if (i==0){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, refList.get(i));
            mp.start();

        }else{

            MediaPlayer mp0 = MediaPlayer.create(this, refList.get(i));
            mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp0);

        }

    }
```

Comment: and Your problem is, You don´t know how to catch the user input and play it with this method?

Comment: my problem is for example my input is a4 and a4, the sound overlaps. i want it to be like play the sound of a4 and then after playing, it will then play again the sound of a4. wihtout them overlapping/

Answer (score 0):

Now I think I understand Your problem, so give this example a try. You said, if You have two equals sounds after another, it will loop. This is because, You creating a complete new MediaPlayer and start it, setNextMediaPlayer() is not executed. This is because of Your first if statement:

```
     if (u.equals("a4")){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a4);
            mp.start();
```

A possible solution could be is, check the i integer of Your loop:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < tempq.size(); i++) {
        String u =tempq.get(i);

        //WHOLE
        if (u.equals("a4")&&i==0){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a4);
            mp.start();

        }else if(u.equals("a4")&&i>0){

            MediaPlayer mp0 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a4);
            mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp0);


        }else if (u.equals("b4")){
            MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b4);
            mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp1);


        }else if (u.equals("c4")){
            MediaPlayer mp2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c4);
            mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);


        }
    }
```

but, Your intention will keep You to the next problem. What if the user selected a completely other one? Let´s say, he will start with b4? Then there will be no origin mediaPlayer to set for setNextMediaPlayer()...
It will be better if You save the references inside an array, so You don´t need all these if/else statements. Let´s say You will have the references as an ArrayList:

```
     ArrayList<Integer> refList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You put the references inside like this:

```
     refList.add(R.raw.a4); //etc.
```

Then You only need to make two if else statements:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < tempq.size(); i++) {

    if (i==0){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, refList.get(i));
        mp.start();

    }else{

        MediaPlayer mp0 = MediaPlayer.create(this, refList.get(i));
        mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp0);

    }
}
```

Comment: regarding to starting in b4, is it possible to do it just like the one you did in a4?

Comment: yes, it should also work...if You set the array like this. If You follow the first example, You have to be sure, that You always start with this one. That´s why I showed the second example...

Comment: i'm a little bit confused about your references suggestion a while ago but now i understand it. i will try it and let you know if it works. thanks a lot!

Comment: what i tried is playing a4 a4 and b4 but after playing 2 sounds  the third sound doesn't play.

Comment: Like I saw on Your update, it´s because You are just adding two sounds into Your list...I suspect, sound a4 is playing, then b4 and then it stops, wright?

Comment: it is inside the for loop so if tempq has 3 items like for example i've added a4, b4, and a4 in tempq, then refList should also have 3 items which is the equivalent of raw.a4, raw.b4 and raw.a4. it is how i understand my code. just correct me if i'm wrong because i am also not sure about it.

Comment: yep, and Your code looks ok, so it should do the work. Have You any errors in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

i've got to solve the issue by doing this. Putting setNextMediaPlayer in every if else statement. and also by comparing if loop is on the 2nd 3rd 4th so on and so forth. i just have to limit my code until the loops gets upto 60.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tempq.size(); i++) {

        if (i==0){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, tempq.get(i));
            mp.start();

        }else if(i==1){

            mp0 = MediaPlayer.create(this, tempq.get(i));
            mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp0);

        }else if(i==2){

            mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, tempq.get(i));
            mp0.setNextMediaPlayer(mp1);

        }else if(i==3){

            mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, tempq.get(i));
            mp1.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);

        }else if(i==4){

            mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, tempq.get(i));
            mp2.setNextMediaPlayer(mp3);

        }else if(i==5){

            mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, tempq.get(i));
            mp3.setNextMediaPlayer(mp4);

        }
```

}

thanks for the idea Opiatefuchs!